# Finding all the properties of an object in Liquid

Tags: iteration, liquid

How can you find all the properties of an object/variable in Liquid?  For example, in the following code, I want to do something that enumerates me all the properties of `child`:

```
  {% for child in site.root_nav_pages %}
    All properties:
    {% for propname in child %}
      Name: {{ propname }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

This doesn't output anything, however.  Is there a way to actually enumerate all an object's properties or are you simply reliant on the documentation to tell you what properties are actually available on an object?